# How to find all images with a certain pixel size using command line?

Tags: command-line, find, metadata

I am trying to find all JPG images within a folder with subfolders that have either width or height below 300px.

This way I want to detect old thumbnails and delete them.

For sure I can find all images using `find`:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f | ...
```

But what follows after the pipe? Which package can I use to detect picture attributes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `identify` from `imagemagick`, and you can use the following command:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | awk '$1<300 || $2<300'
```

the use of `-exec <command> '{}' \;` makes sure that your filename can have spaces in them, alternatively you can use

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f | xargs -I{} identify -format '%w %h %i' {} | awk '$1<300 || $2<300'
```

where the `-I{}` takes care of the same thing.

What I like about `identify` is that you can specify the output format; in this case `'%w %h %i'` which gives the width, height and full pathname of the image. Then the `awk` expression only keeps those lines for which the image is smaller than the desired size.

Example of the output:

```
64 64 ./thumbsup.jpg
100 150 ./photomin.jpg
```

Edit: If you want the filenames only (for piping to `rm` for instance), simply change `$line` in the `awk` statement to `$3`, then it will only print the third column.

Comment: The awk part can be made shorter: `| awk '$1<300||$2<300'` or `| awk '$1<300||$2<300{print $3}'` (when only the 3rd column is needed).

Comment: @har-wradim Thanks, nice suggestion!

Comment: I had to add a newline (`'%w %h %i\n'`) to get it to work for me.

Comment: Sorry for write in a 6 years question, but this is the only result I find on google that partially asnwers my question, basically what I want is find images with or within specific dimensions and then copy them to another directory. I know that cp is used to copy, but I fail at integrate this command with cp.

Comment: @GhostOrder follow the suggestion of @har-wradim to only print the 3rd column, then add another pipe with something like this `| xargs -I {} mv {} /destination/directory/`

Comment: @Gerhard Burger Thanks for the help, I think my problem is that the command outputs the names joining them, is like this `1663 2495 ./0001.jpg2495 1663 ./0072.jpg1663`... and so on, so when I add `| xargs -I {} mv {} /destination/directory/` I get the error `mv: cannot stat './0001.jpg2495': No such file or directory`. How can I output the file names in a correct way?

Comment: Use @qwr suggestion to add a new line :)

Comment: @GerhardBurger i need to set if $1 greater than 1280  convert it to 1280 , that's possible ?

Comment: @MikelTawfik Sure, just use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007722/resize-with-imagemagick-with-a-maximal-width-height (it will leave the smaller files alone)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
find . -iname "*.png" -type f -exec identify -format '%i %wx%h\n' '{}' \; | grep '75x75'
```

This is the output sample:

```
./2520161636481000.png 75x75
./2620160819191100.png 75x75
./2420181545550700.png 75x75
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the accepted answer is very good, but I wanted to add another possible solution ...

Although I use `ImageMagick` tools most often now myself, `netpbm` is an old friend for processing images. You can see the size of any format of image with the command:

```
anytopnm file | pamfile
```

This will generate output that looks like:

```
stdin:  PPM raw, 1650 by 1275  maxval 255
```

To answer the question of "what follows after the pipe?", I use `while read` more often than I use `xargs` because it is more flexible. My `netpbm` answer to the question looks like this:

```
find -iname \*.jpg | while read img; do \
  anytopnm "$img" | pamfile | \
    perl -ane 'exit 1 if $F[3]<300 || $F[5]<300' || rm -v "$img"; \
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `identify` command from the `imagemagick` package does what you want:

```
$ identify abc.jpg
abc.jpg JPEG 1952x3264 1952x3264+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 1.111MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Again, you would need to then use `grep` to sort out the image size.

However, I suspect that unless you have a very wide range of image sizes, it would be easier just to use `find` to remove JPEG files below a given size:

```
find -iname '*.jpg' -size -10k -delete
```

(Worth running without `-delete` first to check it doesn't find things you want to keep - it won't prompt you before deletion otherwise).