# Searching for photos with portrait orientation (height greater than width) with `find` and `exif`

Tags: command-line, find, exif

I have a few gigabytes of digital photos collected over the years in various directories. My current need is to look for photos in portrait mode as against landscape mode. I am trying to write a shell script with the help of the `find` and `exif` commands to see if I can get a list of images.

Portrait mode `exif` information shows that tag "Pixel Y Dimension" is larger than "Pixel X Dimension"

I have managed to get the right commands to get width and height of images:

```
exif -t 0xa002 image.jpg | grep Value | cut -d' ' -f 4 #Width
exif -t 0xa003 image.jpg | grep Value | cut -d' ' -f 4 #Height
```

How could I combine this with the `find` command so that I can find images where height is larger than width?

And, is there any way I can make it more generic - like find photos with certain date (in the exif data) or exif values?

Comment: It seems that it's much easier to write a simple python script than try to fit this task in bash (this article can help: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/28/getting-photo-metadata-exif-using-python/)

Comment: @user502144 if you can write a python script to do this and post it as an answer, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

We can use a modified version of this answer: [How to find all images with a certain pixel size using commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238136/how-to-find-all-images-with-a-certain-pixel-size-using-commandline)

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | awk '$1<$2'
```