# how to find all pictures with a certain aspect ratio in a directory and its subdirectories

Tags: command-line, image-processing

I need a method to find all pictures with a certain aspect ratio, for example 16:9 , such as 1920x1080 1280x720 944x531.

I found this page [How to find all images with a certain pixel size using command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238136/how-to-find-all-images-with-a-certain-pixel-size-using-command-line) but it only says how to find certain sizes not aspect ratios.

I use bash.

Comment: Divide the sizes to get the aspect ratio?  landscape: 16/9 = 1.77... and in portrait: 9/16=0.5625.

Comment: how do I divide the sizes in command line
and how do I pass the result of the check to grep? maybe I should make it a function and have it have a if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the command from your link
[How to find all images with a certain pixel size using command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238136/how-to-find-all-images-with-a-certain-pixel-size-using-command-line)

This will print filenames with pictures approximatly landscape 16/9:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' '{}' \; | awk '$1/$2>1.7 && $1/$2<1.8 {print $3}'
```

This will do the same with approximatly portrait 9/16:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' '{}' \; | awk '$1/$2>0.5 && $1/$2<0.6 {print $3}'
```

Of course you can use the math in awk in more sophisticated way (for better reading only the  awk part):

```
awk 'sqrt((($1/$2)-(16/9))^2)<sqrt(0.5^2) {print $3}'
```

As awk has no "abs" function, I just use created it using "^2" and "sqrt" to check if the ratio is inside a "delta" (in this example 0.5).

Comment: this has a bug. the format has to be `-format '%w %h %i\n'`

Comment: and also it only prints upto first space in the name. it works otherwise.

Comment: a good fix for that is {print substr($0, index($0,$3)) }

Comment: Thanks, updated it.

Comment: even better way to print the name in full if it has spaces: `{$1=$2=""; print $0}` instead of `{print $3}`